# jQuery Slide round button(pre-next) custom

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

http://wex.im/javascript/jquery-slider2

I used this source.
This slide show Pre-Next button like this -> ●●...
And I want to show button like this -> ①②...(Numbering + BG color)

Is this possible? 
If this is possible, should I fix what language(code?)?
For example CSS, Jquery, HTML...

**Button CSS code**

```
.jquery-slider-pages {
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    right: 5px;
}
.jquery-slider-page {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #999;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.33;
    margin: 3px;
    behavior:url("https://dwp.konami/j-com/PIE.htc");
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: #333 0 0 2px;
}
.jquery-slider-page:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
}
.jquery-slider-page-current {
    opacity: 0.8;
    background: #1C1C1C;
}
```

**button jQuery code**

```
var _draw=function()
{
    $this.addClass('jquery-slider-sliding');
    if(settings.showProgress)
    {
        $this.find('.jquery-slider-page').removeClass('jquery-slider-page-current');
        $this.find('.jquery-slider-page:eq('+(_this.nextAll('.jquery-slider-element').length)+')').addClass('jquery-slider-page-current');
    }
    settings.slidebefore(_this,
    $this);

    if(settings.direction=='right')
    {
        _this.show().css('left',
        -settings.width);
    }
    else
    {   
        _this.show().css('left',
        settings.width);
    }

    _this.stop(true,true).animate(
    {'left':(settings.direction=='right'?'+=':'-=')+settings.width+'px'},
        {
            'duration':settings.fade,
            'complete':function()
            {
                settings.slideafter(_this,
                $this);
                $this.removeClass('jquery-slider-sliding');
            }
        }
    );

    if(_last)
    {
        _last.stop(true,true).animate({'left':(settings.direction=='right'?'+=':'-=')+settings.width+'px'},{'duration':settings.fade});
    }
};
```

**HTML code**

```
<div id='slider'>
<div id ='link'>
<a href='test.html'target ='_blank'>
TEST</a>
</div>
<div id ='link'>
<a href='test2.html'target ='_blank'>
TEST2</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it can be done by the help of jquery here is a link of free slider download it and study [JSSOR SLIDER](http://www.jssor.com/demos/introduction-slider.html)

i think it will be of help

Answer (score 1):

You can use some better slider than that, which does have better api and provides you more functionality.. This one will surely fulfill your need.. check it out.

[Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

and a demo on this which suits your needs..

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html